# insert values inside table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Eu preciso criar um `input` dentro de uma célula de uma `table` usando JavaScript. Eu criei uma tag `<a>` com `name="ex2"`

```
<tr><p>
<td id="secTd"><label for="cAp"><a id="num">02</a> <a id="texto">Time</a></label></td>
<td id="tecTd"><a name="ex2"></a></td>
</p></tr>
```

E estou usando este código JavaScript para escrever "val1" dentro desta tag.

```
document.getElementById("exibe1").innerHTML = "val1";
```

Não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro, mesma coisa se eu tentar com um `input`.

Comment: Eu tentei traduzir, mas a pergunta me parece não fazer nenhum sentido.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem, o problema é apenas buscar com JavaScript um elemento cujo `id` é `exibe1` enquanto o elemento desejado nem `id` definido possui. Podes, então, definir devidamente a propriedade no elemento ou fazer:

```js
document.querySelector("a[name='ex2']").innerHTML = "val1";
```

```html
<tr>
  <p>
    <td id="secTd"><label for="cAp"><a id="num">02</a> <a id="texto">Time</a></label></td>
    <td id="tecTd">
      <a name="ex2"></a>
    </td>
  </p>
</tr>
```

> Este elemento `p` definido dentro do `tr` não me parece fazer sentido.